# X3D-Edit running script issue in OSX

Tags: macos, x3d

I'm trying to make X3D-Edit 3.3 work, installed it on OSX 10.9.1 but I can't make it work properly.
When I run the "runX3dEditMac.sh.command" script, X3D-Edit succesfully loads, the User Interface seems being ok but once I start using it, it freeze as soon as I close the Xj3d window and Palette icons don't even seem to work (except for the first group in the Palette panel).
I noticed these lines in the Terminal after launching X3D-Edit:

```
./runX3dEditMac.sh.command: line 22: -J-Xms32m: command not found
./runX3dEditMac.sh.command: line 25: -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true: command not found
./runX3dEditMac.sh.command: line 26: -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled: command not found
```

The Default runX3dEditMac.sh.command script code is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Shell file to run X3D-Edit 3.2

# First make sure we're running 1.6, will bomb if not
source javaVersionCheck.sh

# Memory settings for X3D-Edit 3.2:  see ReadmeX3D-EditMemorySettings.txt
# The default settings for a zipped app exist in x3deditor32/etc/x3deditor32.conf
# The stack (-Xss2m) setting is under evaluation and may need
# increasing because of recursive routines in XML and XSLT processing.

# Xms768m allocates 768 Mb to the Java heap on startup.  Xmx768m sets a limit on incremental allocations to the heap.
# If your usage case will normally always require the maximum, set both and performance will slightly increase
# because incremental allocations (to the OS) are eliminated.

# Examples:
# -J-Xss2m
# -J-Xss2m -J-Xmx768m
# -J-Xss2m -J-Xms768m -J-Xmx768m

# and do it this way (showing alternative values for ms and mx):
MEMORYSETTINGS0=-J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Xmx2g -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=384m -J-Xverify:none
#MEMORYSETTINGS1='-J-Xms1g'
#MEMORYSETTINGS2='-J-Xmx1g'
LOOKANDFEELSETTINGS=-J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dswing.aatext=true
GCSETTINGS=-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy

# Use the quoting mess to handle spaces in the path
THISDIR=`dirname "$0"`
cd "$THISDIR"
cd x3deditor32/bin
sh x3deditor32 -J-client -J-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 $GCSETTINGS $LOOKANDFEELSETTINGS "$MEMORYSETTINGS0" "$MEMORYSETTINGS1" "$MEMORYSETTINGS2" -J-Djava.endorsed.dirs=endorsedjars
```

I read here http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/X3D-Edit#Tips that I should use a 32-bit JDK but I couldn't find any JDK 7 32-bit version for OSX!

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Bash is interpreting the values, which also contain spaces. To fix this:

Surround the variable values with quotes e.g.:
    MEMORYSETTINGS0="-J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Xmx2g -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=384m -J-Xverify:none"

Then remove the quotes where the variables are actually used e.g.:

sh x3deditor32 -J-client -J-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 $GCSETTINGS $LOOKANDFEELSETTINGS $MEMORYSETTINGS0 $MEMORYSETTINGS1 $MEMORYSETTINGS2 -J-Djava.endorsed.dirs=endorsedjars

Here is a corrected version:

https://gist.github.com/aodhol/53d3a0f786571cc620c4

Note, it also has a fix for the issue that some people ran into where they got the error:

```
'line 5: /javaVersionCheck.sh: No such file or directory'
```

allowing the .command file to be executed directly in the windowing environment rather than at the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your response Aodh, by substituting the original runX3dEditMac.sh.command with the one you linked successfully removed the bash warnings I had but unfortunately it still freeze; I'm starting to think that the Xj3d window is the one to blame for it. I'm running it on OS X 10.9.2, with jdk1.7.0_55.

Comment: Did it give you the option to disable plugins? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Yes it did: http://i59.tinypic.com/23qw4l.jpg and http://i59.tinypic.com/beh5xy.jpg

Comment: Tested with X3D-Edit 3.3 and JRE 1.6. Are you running from the Terminal or from the Finder?

Comment: I'm running it from the Finder, I'll try to test it with JRE 1.6 then.

Comment: I tried to install a Java 6 version on Mavericks but then executing the runX3dEditMac.sh.command gave me this: Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7.0_10". Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.

Comment: ok, stating the obvious, maybe undo what you did or use the --jdkhome option pointing to the location where the JDK is installed. Have you tried running from the Terminal: './runX3dEditMac.sh.command' from within the directory where X3D Edit is installed?

Comment: I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable by using the following shell command: export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.6`. Checking the current java version with java -version in fact gives: java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode). But when i use the script you gave me it prints the warnings I already showed you and this one in the shell: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: disabling UseAdaptiveSizePolicy; it is incompatible with UseConcMarkSweepGC.

Comment: How am I supposed to use jdkhome? Sorry but I'm new to Java.